# Mathematics for special and general relativity .

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, vector-spaces, tensors

I want to know what kind of mathematics should i learn to well understand the special and general theory of relativity , as i have a book for general theory of relativity but it seems the mathematics used is more complicated that normal but i don't know what it's name , so i need advice what kind of math is that  to study it.

Comment: Maybe [Tensor calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_calculus).

Comment: Please tell us the name and author of the relativity book you already have.

Comment: The name of the book is "The General theory of relativity , a mathematical exposition "

Comment: But why you need the name .

Comment: See [page xi](https://books.google.it/books?id=wJR7SmPedWcC&pg=PR11): **Tensor Analysis**.

Comment: The first statement of the text refers to dedicated textbooks; e.g. Bishop, R.L. and Goldberg, S.I., *Tensor analysis on manifolds*, Das, A., *Tensors: The mathematics of relativity theory & continuum mechanics*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  do you know what kind of scince that studied the geometry of curvature surfaces .

Comment: Differential geometray maybe. Recall there is a book called "gravity", which has got three authors.

Comment: The math is tensor analysis, tensor analysis, and differential geometry.  Any math textbook on these subjects is likely to be very similar to the book you already have.  To see how the math is actually used, I recommend youtube videos.  The Geometry of Physics lectures by Fredric Schuller, the general relativity lectures by Alexander Maloney and the tensor / manifold lectures by XylyXylyX come to mind.  There are many more.

Comment: For special relativity, you need linear algebra about quadratic and bilinear forms, and some group theory about groups (the Lorentz group) that preserves bilinear form. Some knowledge on multilinear algebra (i.e. tensors) would also be needed.